# Use VLookup to see if selected cell is in a range?

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I've seen how to say "Is cell x in range y" but since I'm using `VLookup` I'm not sure how to reconcile the two.

Basically, the code below does a lookup on a table that contains tips and then displays them in a specified cell.  It works great.  What I would *like* to do is specify an entire range of cells in the lookup table, then if the user selects any cell within that range the tip is displayed.  As it stands, if I have a large area of say 10 cells I have to create 10 duplicate entries in the lookup table (one for each cell).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cellTitle As Range
    Set cellTitle = Range("J2")
    Dim cellTip As Range
    Set cellTip = Range("J3")
    
    If Target.Address = "$J$3:$K$5" Or Target.Address = "$J$2:$K$2" Or Target.Address = "$K$1" Then
        'leave existing content in case user wants to copy tip
    Else
        Range("K1").Value = Target.Address
        Title = Application.VLookup(Target.Address, Sheets("Settings").Range("TipsDashboard"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(Title) Then
            Tip = Application.VLookup(Target.Address, Sheets("Settings").Range("TipsDashboard"), 3, False)
            cellTitle.Value = Title
            cellTip.Value = Tip
        Else
            cellTitle.Value = "Tips & Instructions"
            cellTip.Value = "Try selecting various fields to get dynamic tips or instructions in this space."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is a sample of my lookup table:

[image]

You'll notice there are ranges here, but they are merged cells.

Comment: Have you tried `find`?

Comment: I've never used the `find` function, no.

Comment: Learn something new today! Edit: huh. I am looking at your table and I am confused. You actually built cells into a column to look up??

Comment: [Find Example](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find%20Data%20in%20other%20Sheet)

Comment: Yes, so I can add a comment for any cell on the "Dashboard" worksheet.  It's really neat, in my humble opinion. :)

Comment: To elaborate, this is a pretty complex sheet that we send to our customers.  Even if they change the values of the fields they need to fill out, I want the "Tips" cell to display information about the cell they have selected.

Comment: There's no way to put this bluntly but I don't think it's really neat. Instead, rather convoluted XD No offense meant but if you're using a worksheet change event, your coding prowess can't be that bad so please consider better architecture.

Comment: How would you recommend associating an instruction with a cell?

Comment: Search for the instruction? I am unclear to what you're doing. But it _rarely_ makes sense to use a worksheet function _within_ code. Make sense?

Comment: I'm confused, is the problem the `VLookup` or having a cell reference in the lookup table?

Comment: Architecture. Why are you using a worksheet function when you know how to code? Edit: perhaps there is really no way. I am asking you to reevaluate.

Comment: You're saying this could be easier than a single line? ie `cellTitle.Value = Application.VLookup(Target.Address, Sheets("Settings").Range("TipsDashboard"), 2, False)`

Comment: Ah. No, it will be _more_ lines most likely. But far better architecture. For instance, you won't have to rebuild it when entries grow.

Comment: What entries?  I can add as many values as I want to the lookup table and I don't have to "rebuild" anything?  But seriously, I digress.  We're obviously not "getting" eachother.

Comment: And as you add more entries, you find you need to add more `vlookups`? The hard part of programming isn't coding. It's architecture ^_^;

Comment: Can you do something with [Application.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx)?

Comment: This is a total hack, but you could put some string in the "ID" property of each cell.  So in each cell in $B$5:$C$8 you could put "$B$5:$C$8" as the ID property.  Then lookup the ID property of the target cell instead of the target cell address.  This only works if you don't plan on saving the document as a webpage.  You'd have to set the property via VBA for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

**edited**: made so that it's possible to associate different cells in active sheet to the same range value in "cell" column of" Settings" sheet

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim cellTitle As Range, cellTip As Range, found As Range

    Set cellTitle = Range("J2")
    Set cellTip = Range("J3")

    If target.address = "$J$3:$K$5" Or target.address = "$J$2:$K$2" Or target.address = "$K$1" Then
        'leave existing content in case user wants to copy tip
    Else
        Range("K1").Value = target.address

        Set found = GetCell(target, Sheets("Settings").Range("TipsDashboard").Columns(1))
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            cellTitle.Value = found.Offset(, 1)
            cellTip.Value = found.Offset(, 2)
        Else
            cellTitle.Value = "Tips & Instructions"
            cellTip.Value = "Try selecting various fields to get dynamic tips or instructions in this space."
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Function GetCell(target As Range, sourceRng As Range) As Range
Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range

With target
    For Each cell In sourceRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Set cell2 = GetRangeFromAddress(.Parent, cell.Value)
        If Not cell2 Is Nothing Then
            If Not Intersect(.cells, cell2) Is Nothing Then
                Set GetCell = cell
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Function


Function GetRangeFromAddress(sht As Worksheet, address As String) As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set GetRangeFromAddress = sht.Range(address)
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```